# How to merge duplicate rows based on columns that are not empty?

Tags: sql

I'm dealing with the problem of working with a dirty customer database. There are many duplicates due to different spellings and maintenance quality of the data.
For example the data looks like this:

[image]

My goal is to merge rows generically based on the name, so the empty columns are automatically filled with the value contained in another row:
[image]

Is there a way in SQL to do something like that?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Look at `group by` and `max()`. Please post actual data as *text*, not as [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data.

Comment: If there are two different phones for one person, which one wuld you keep?

Comment: Please post data samples as text, not picture

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name,
       MAX(Address) Address,
       MAX(Zip) Zip,
       MAX(Mail) Mail,
       MAX(Phone) Phone,
       MAX(City) City
FROM customer
GROUP BY Name
```